# Open a Stub from a Resource

Tags: vb.net, build, resources

I'm trying to experiment with Stubs and all the tutorials I've seen tell you to get the Stub.exe as so:

```
FileOpen(1, Application.StartupPath & "\sub.exe", OpenMode.Binary, OpenAccess.Read)
```

This was the explaination later on:

```
FileOpen(Reference number, file name including the path, mode to open the file as, Mode Of Access)
```

Im trying to input the Stub from a resource in my project but when I add it to the line(it looks like this:)

```
FileOpen(1, My.Resources.Stub, OpenMode.Binary, OpenAccess.Read, OpenShare.Default)
```

It then underlines it in Red and says:

> Value of Type '1-dimensional array of Byte' cannot be converted to
>   'String'.

I believe what that is trying to say is that the .exe cannot be put into a String? Correct me if im wrong...

My full code is below:

```
Public Class Form1
    Const FileSplit As String = "|split|"
    Dim stub, text1, button As String
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim sfd As New SaveFileDialog
        sfd.Filter = "Executables(.exe)|*.exe"
        If sfd.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            text1 = TextBox1.Text
            button = TextBox2.Text
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If

        FileOpen(1, My.Resources.Stub, OpenMode.Binary, OpenAccess.Read, OpenShare.Default)
        stub = Space(LOF(1))
        FileGet(1, stub)
        FileClose(1)

        FileOpen(1, sfd.FileName, OpenMode.Binary, OpenAccess.ReadWrite, OpenShare.Default)
        FilePut(1, stub & FileSplit & text1 & FileSplit & button)
        FileClose(1)

        MsgBox("Success")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

copy the stub from resources into the application startup folder using code.  use the code to copy the stub in the "form load".   so that when ever you transfer the appthe stub is there also as soon as you open the app.

Answer (score 0):

use this code :  this works with my binder, im using this...
put this code in your form1.load........  email me if doesnt work
at  jhonniewalker58@gmail.com

```
 If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(Application.StartupPath & "\stub.exe") = False Then
        IO.File.WriteAllBytes(Application.StartupPath & "\stub.exe", My.Resources.stub)
    End If
```